# Why does Windbg display the registers as incrementing by 1

Tags: assembly, x86, windbg

I've attached to a process and upon executing the `.frame /r` command to show the register values, they all increment by 1 (as shown below).  This is at each point through the process when using `u` to unassemble it, even though there data should be going to the registers they remain the same.  Why is this happening?

Part of the output in windgb:

```
ebx=00000001 ecx=00000002 edx=00000003 esi=00000004 edi=00000005
```

Comment: Maybe this is a version specific question. For me, with WinDbg 6.2.9200.16384 and 6.3.9600.16384, `.frame /r` shows the same output as `r` and does not have 1, 2, 3, 4 as values. Which version are you using?

Comment: Hmm strange, I'm using 6.12.0002.633 @ThomasW.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce with WinDbg 6.12.0002.633. Are you sure that these values cannot be the correct values? Do you have the source code of what's currently executing?

Comment: I don't have the source code, but it appears to be that the registers a staying static.  It happens with process I attach to and programs I run, for example I'll see a register with 0f0f0f0f and it will be xor'd against itself but remain 0f0f0f0f @ThomasW.